# how to make android studio to display files in the project directory by date created

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I want all my xml files in the layout folder to be shown in the ascending but I want it to be shown order of date created is there any to do it like we can "sort by date" in windows explorer

[image: in the image it's being displayed in alphabetical order]